# Power Query: try ... otherwise on list item expression

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Why does catching the following index-error fail:

```
let
    Source = "abc",
    letter_list = Text.ToList(Source),
    try_on_index_error = try letter_list{5}
in
    try_on_index_error
```

The `try` statement does not return an `Error` record. It keeps throwing the error as if no `try` was present.

In this case it works as expected, returning an `Error` record as a valid result of the query:

```
let
    Source = "abc",
    try_another_error = try Source + 1,
    Error = try_another_error[Error]
in
    Error
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/handlingerrors#catching-an-error-with-try-and-otherwise

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-consolidated-grammar#error-handling-expression

Comment: To me, this looks more like a bug than something with a good explanation. It seems like an index out of bounds should be something that can be handled with `try` rather than breaking the query with an "Unexpected error".

Comment: Take a look at [Lazy Evaluation & Query Folding in Power BI / Power Query](https://www.thepoweruser.com/2019/03/19/lazy-evaluation-query-folding-in-power-bi-power-query/).  If you buffer your list, it will work as expected:  `letter_list = List.Buffer(Text.ToList(Source)),`

Comment: Cheers @ron, I think that would help others as an answer, too. (Your solution works fine.) One thing I wonder about: I also ran my un-buffered code for a valid item access like `try letter_list{1}` and here the `Error` record _is_ returned (of course with `[Error][HasError] = false`).

Answer (score 0):

It is naturally hard to answer questions on the behavior of closed-source software. However, the comment by Ron Rosenfeld solved my trouble:

```
letter_list = List.Buffer(Text.ToList(Source))
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-introduction#evaluation) (last paragraph in chapter *Evaluation*) explain the unexpected behavior: Lazy evaluation is done for lists, records and let-expressions. As seen above, in case of lazy evaluation, `try` statement falls back to syntax checking, supposedly.